# redirecting router connections to different subnet

Tags: dhcp, subnet

I'm pretty new at networking and I'm not sure how to make all router connections go to a different subnet.

For example my subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 and I have three scopes: 10.0.1.1-255 / 10.0.2.1-255 / 10.0.3.1-255 .
I want to make all router connections go for example to 10.0.5.1-50 . So should I make some kind of policy on the DHCP server or what?

Comment: That is way to broad a question. Maybe set down 3 points. 1. What subnets do you want to route. 2. How many routers do you want to use. 3. How are the subnets separated?

Comment: hmm maybe i asked wrong , is it possible that dhcp server would see the difference between physical and wireless connection because they are going through the same switch and are in the same subnet scope, the only thing i need is just that from 10.0.1 they would go to 10.0.4 for example.

Comment: You're kind of mixing and matching things, you can assign gateway (default router) addresses through DHCP, but usually you need to identify the clients in some manner to allow the DHCP server to distribute different IPs and gateway routers. You could use MAC addresses, or have traffic from different networks arrive on different NICs..

Comment: if its default gateway then it will only find the ones who are going outside the network, and what about if you assign access point address?

Comment: If your default gateway is attached to all the subnets, it can let people talk to all the subnets. Anyhow, I still don't understand what you're looking to do, you need to explain what you have (subnets, routers, clients) and what you want (one router for the wireless, one for the wired, for example..).

Comment: all clients and routers are on the same switch and has same gateway all of them are going in the same subnet scope 10.0.1.1-255/24 and i need that the ones who are going throught wireless would be somehow moved to another scope 10.0.3.1-255/24 for example

Comment: Ah, so you want to give the people on the wireless network a different subnet 10.0.3.x, while people who have wired connections get 10.0.1.x addresses?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i need!:D

Comment: Well it depends on what you are distributing the DHCP addresses with, if I had to do this, I'd have a DHCP server connected to the wired network for the 10.0.1.x network, and I'd enable DHCP to distribute 10.0.3.x on the wireless AP/Router.

Comment: But how do i enable dhcp to distribute 10.0.3 on ap router is it through router configuration or dhcp server itself?

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter the routing table of your router or firewall. Not the DHCP server unless this is what connects all 3 subnets. This is googlable, and you can also visit [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/531872/corporate-vpn-internet-traffic-tracing/532131#532131) for more info on routing tables.

Comment: well i'm not sure because i'm a new intern at this company and my supervisor asked me to this and he said it doesnt have anything to do with the routing tables it should be something with policies or something like that.

Comment: Just so we're clear, you want `subnet A` to talk to `subnet B`, correct? The only way to do that is to tell the router that they are supposed to talk to each other, otherwise they will only talk to their own subnet.